# How to select table and count other table

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Suppose I have two tables:

Customers

```
  Name   |   id   |
-------------------
  Benny  |    1   |
  Wilson |    2   |
  Joe    |    3   |
  Austin |    4   |
```

Orders

```
  Product  |   id   |
---------------------
  TV       |    1   |
  Hifi-set |    1   |
  HTPC     |    1   |
  CD       |    1   |
  DVD      |    1   |
  CD       |    1   |
  DVD      |    1   |
```

And this is what I want with the results:

```
  Name   | Orders |
-------------------
  Benny  |    7   |
  Wilson |    0   |
  Joe    |    0   |
  Austin |    0   |
```

I'm not familiar with SQL, But I tried:

```
SELECT c.Name FROM Customers AS c LEFT JOIN Orders AS o ON c.id=o.id GROUP BY c.Name
```

But got a wrong result:

```
  Name   | Orders |
-------------------
  Benny  |    4   |
  Wilson |    1   |
  Joe    |    1   |
  Austin |    1   |
```

What do I do?

Comment: RobB's nested `SELECT`s query is perfectly valid, but for the record your query is probably correct other than that you're joining customer IDs to order IDs.  You probably need `C.ID = O.CustomerID` or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
select 
   c.Name, 
   (select count(1) from Orders where ID=c.ID) 
from 
   Customers as c
```

Answer (score 1):

By not using `SubQuery`, you can also `JOIN` instead.

```
SELECT   a.Name, COUNT(b.id)
FROM     Customers a LEFT JOIN Orders b
            on a.ID = b.ID
GROUP BY a.Name
```

Comment: This is a much more efficient solution than the one marked as accepted. One thing to improve it would be to `GROUP BY` also by the `id`, in case there are one or more customers with the same name.